# Multiple Web Projects in a single ASP.NET Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, modularity

Is it really possible to have a two different asp.net web projects in a single web solution ? For instance here's the current structure

+Solution
 -CoreModule
 -CustomModule
 -WebProject

In this same hierarchy, can I have this

+Solution
 -CoreModule
 -CustomModule
 -WebProject
 -NewWebProjectModule

And use the web pages defined on NewWebProjecModule inside WebProject and use the style defined in WebProject inside NewWebProjectModule ?

What I am trying to do is separate the modules in the web project to have less clutter ?

Or would I be better of doing a control library as different project OR have the business rules on a separate module and have the UI on the main web project ?

Comment: That's an architectural design question, not a programming question. I suggest you do some research ;-)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I did do some research :). In the question, I have three approaches that I wanted to use. I wanted to know if there are any best practices out there in the world that I would need to know of.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can very much have more than one web project in a Visual Studio Solution. While debugging with VS, you will have to run the required one.

If you have contents/controls that get replicated/reused in both web projects, I would prefer to have them in a common library/module and use them as required.

Comment: So you are suggesting, for a control library project and refer that in the web project ? In that case would it make sense for the POCO classes to remain in the control library ?

Comment: If your POCO classes are business entities, they can remain in a separate library other than the one for controls. This would help you in using them across the solution. The control library can consist of reusable controls for the web tier of the application. They would be used only by the web projects. This will have a better "separation of concerns".